# What could possibly convert null to Infinity?

Tags: javascript

In my React+Redux application, the value of **null** after performing certain kinds of operations is being (implicitly) converted to **Infinity** somehow, I can't seem to find the reason.

What are the possible subtle ways that could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools), which is not capable of displaying **Infinity** and uses **null** to denote it.

Already created an issue request on GitHub.

I was console.loging the prop that holds a value of **Infinity** in different parts of my application, while Redux DevTools has been displaying this value as **null** at the same time.